# Where does the constructor invocation get stored? Stack or Heap?

Tags: java

When an object is created and the constructor is called where does the constructor invocation get stored? is it on a stack or heap?

Comment: Useful read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826222/jvm-heap-and-stack/7597480#7597480

Comment: Calling the constructor is just like calling a special method called `<init>` It uses the stack like any other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heap is only meant for storing objects . There is no way to have constructor invoked on heap.

**It's invocation is done on stack.**

Stack is used in method calling. It is used for creating method stacks. Although constructor is not a method. But you can always write any logic or assignment as is always done In any method. So it's implemented in a stack like any other method.

Answer (score 4):

The parameters and local variables for the constructor call are stored on the stack until the constructor returns.

The object that the constructor creates is stored in the heap<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - ... unless you have "escape analysis" enabled, and the JIT compiler can determine that the object can be safely allocated on the stack.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Runtime data area in JVM for stack and heap is as below,

1) Heap : Storage area for Objects.(One per JVM instance)

2) Java stack: Storage are for local variables, results of intermediate operations.(One per thread)