# How we can write binary, octal and hexadecimal literals of floating point numbers in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, literals

How we can write binary, octal and hexadecimal literals of floating point numbers in Java? Either in scientific or in normal representation.

```
class First
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                double b = 0x12p3;
                System.out.println(b);
        }
}
```

The above program results 144.0

```
class First
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                double b = 0x12e3;
                System.out.println(b);
        }
}
```

The above program results 4835.0

```
class First
{
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                    double b = 0x12e3;
                    System.out.println(b);
            }
}
```

The above program results 4835.0

```
class First
{
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                    double b = 012e3;
                    System.out.println(b);
            }
}
```

The above program results 12000

Please explain above outputs.

Comment: Not your down-voter in your last question, but [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805105/where-does-the-constructor-invocation-get-stored-stack-or-heap) are relevant. Note that it's always a good idea to [first search before asking](https://www.google.com/#q=java+does+calling+a+constructor+use+stack+memory)

Answer (score 1):

The first example is a HexadecimalFloatingPointLiteral, (16+2)*8 = 144.

The second and third example is actually a HexIntegerLiteral assigned to a double variable, 1*16*16*16 + 2*16*16 + 14*16 + 3 = 4835. Note that the 'e' is just the hex digit for 14.

The last example is a DecimalFloatingPointLiteral, 12 * 1000.

Java does not support an octal floating point literals.

For all the details see the JLS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2